# C basic code: Table of Precedence/Associativity

Tags: c

```
printf("%d", 7 - 9 % 4 * 2);
```

I got 3 as my printed answer but the answer was 5. Can anyone tell me why I got this wrong?

Comment: I get 5, like expected. Are you sure there's nothing else that's wrong with your program?

Comment: compare: http://goo.gl/8enkEU

Comment: this was written on a test, and i'm trying to find out why my logic was wrong when i took it.

Comment: in general, depending on the precedence can lead to problems.  much better to be explicit by including parens to group operations.  I.E. '7 - (9 % 4) * 2'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplication, division, and modulus have the same precedence, and they all have higher precedence than addition and subtraction.  If two operators have the same precedence, they are (in most cases) evaluated left to right.

So the expression effectively looks like this:

```
7 - ((9 % 4) * 2)
```

Which gives you:

```
7 - ((9 % 4) * 2) = 7 - (1 * 2) = 7 - 2 = 5
```

You probably did division instead of modulus:

```
7 - ((9 / 4) * 2) = 7 - (2 * 2) = 7 - 4 = 3
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! just realized I divided instead of using the module